# Baixar Plugin Genymotion no Eclipse

Tags: android, android-eclipse, genymotion

Galera, não consigo instalar o plugin do Genymotion no meu Eclipse, ele não aparece pra fazer a opção de download, me ajudem por favor[image: ![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzBDz.jpg)

Comment: Recomendo baixar ele separedamente  e rodar via linha de comando.

Answer (score 0):

A princípio você está fazendo certo. Adicionando o link de download e apertando em 'Add' para procurar o plugin. Você poderia dar mais detalhes sobre o passo a passo que você está fazendo e quais mensagens você está recebendo da IDE?

Outra coisa, recomendo que você baixe o Android Studio para programar apps Android, não só porque o Android Studio é feito completamente para programação Android, com todas as ferramentas que você possa imaginar e por ser mais rápido e ter um sistema de build bem mlhr (Gradle), mas principalmente pq [o Google já falou que não irá mais dar suporte ao plugin pra Eclipse](http://www.developer-tech.com/news/2015/jun/29/google-finishes-eclipse-end-support-ide/)

Comment: Nenhuma mensagem, não acontece nada, é que o curso que estou fazendo é no eclipse e sou iniciante nisso

Comment: @DaniloAlbergardi recomendo trocar de curso

Answer (score 0):

Basta desmarcar os check box abaixo.

```
Show only latest versions of available software
Group items by category
```

Depois disso vai aparecer o Genymotion Eclipse Tools.